# Can't create a spring-controller

Tags: jhipster

### Question

What do I need to do to get basename defined in JHipster's **spring-controller generation**?

### Problem

I'm attempting to use JHipster to generate a spring-controller.  It fails to generate, giving the stacktrace copied below.  Further investigation shows that this is crashing because basename is undefined (module.exports.getAngularAppName needs basename to have a value).

Other JHipster generators (gateway, microservice, monolith, spring-service) are working fine, so it's not a general configuration issue.

I've tried adding getTheModuleName() from similarly patterned JHipster generators to spring-controller/prompts.js, but it doesn't work because this.getModuleName() doesn't exist.  I can't find where getModuleName() IS defined, nor do I understand what "this" is within prompts.

I'm a JHipster noob so I'm assuming I'm missing something simple.

Any help would be appreciated.

### Version info

- JHipster Generator v4.13.0
- nodejs 8.9.3
- Fresh installs from nodejs on up as of yesterday
- Other JHipster generators are working fine, so it's not a general configuration issue.

### Inputs/outputs

```
C:\yesOnWindows>jhipster spring-controller fum
Using JHipster version installed globally
Executing jhipster:spring-controller fum
Options:
The spring-controller fum is being created.
? Do you want to add an action to your controller? Yes
? What is the name of your action? fff
? What is the HTTP method of your action? GET
? Do you want to add an action to your controller? No
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'endsWith' of undefined
    at module.exports.getAngularAppName (C:\Users\Dad\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\generator-base.js:2090:56)
    at module.exports.getMainClassName (C:\Users\Dad\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\generator-base.js:2113:40)
    at module.exports.writing (C:\Users\Dad\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster\generators\spring-controller\index.js:83:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dad\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:399:25)
    at C:\Users\Dad\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\run-async\index.js:25:25
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Dad\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\node_modules\run-async\index.js:24:19
    at self.env.runLoop.add.completed (C:\Users\Dad\nodejs\node_modules\generator-jhipster\node_modules\yeoman-generator\lib\index.js:400:11)
    at runCallback (timers.js:789:20)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:751:5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JHipster spring generators are intended to be used in a generated JHipster project.  The generator reads the `baseName` property from the project's `.yo-rc.json` file ([for example here](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-ng2/blob/e9d4b21c0ff27ab8ee92c4560f13b2a5eabf46fb/.yo-rc.json#L4)).  Without first generating a project, JHipster won't be able to generate a Java file that compiles.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!   I was trying to build it in a new directory.